# While loop is not executing at all and everything else looks right

Tags: python

I cannot get this while loop to work. Every time, it says something is wrong with it and I have NO idea what. I've tried capitalizing and uncapitalizing, tabbing, just about everything. I'm truly at my wits end, please help

```
def inputM():
  print("Enter weight in kg")
  weightm = float(input())
  print("Enter heigh in meters")
  heightm = float(input())
  return weightm, heightm
def inputI():
  print("Enter weight in pounds")
  weighti = float(input())
  print("Enter height in inches")
  heighti = float(input())
  return weighti, heighti

def healthindex (BMIList, BMINum, bmi, healthy):
  if healthy == "b": 
    print (str(bmi))
  elif healthy == "h":
    index = 0
    print ("Your bmi is" + (str(bmi))
    while index < len(BMIList):
      if bmi < BMINum[index]:
        print ("And, you are " + BMIList[index])
        return
      index = index + 1
    print("You are Obese")
  return

BMIList = ["severly underweight", "underweight", "healthy", "overweight", "obese"]
BMINum = [12, 18.4, 24.9, 29.9, 200]
print("Welcome to BMI Calculator!")
print("Enter I for Imperial or M for Metric")
request = input().upper()

if request == "M":
  weightm, heightm = inputM()
  bmi = weightm/(heightm**2)
elif request == "I":
  weighti, heighti = inputI()
  bmi = (703*weighti)/(heighti**2)  
else:
  print("Invalid input")

print("Enter b to only see your bmi or enter h if you would like to see your bmi and health index")

healthy= input()
healthindex (BMIList, BMINum, bmi, healthy)
```

Comment: Are you sure that you reach the line before `while`?

Comment: Yes, I went through and fixed that, but it's still not working

Comment: How many arguments do you pass to the `healthindex` function when you call it? How many does it expect?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
We also expect that you will trace the offending values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?

Comment: The code keeps stopping at the while loop, that is where the problem is. I am not sure what is so wrong with this while loop; I even pasted in code someone else posted and the issue with the while loop remains

Comment: Please don't "fix" the problem in your question, that makes it worthless fot future viewers. If you want to answer your own question, then please post an actual answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error in the print statement above the while loop.  You are missing the closing parenthesis as you can see from the following snippet of your code:

```
print ("Your bmi is" + str(bmi)
while index < len(BMIList):
```

Comment: you need another closing parenthesis.